# How to serve HLS using Wowza over port 80 in a server that also uses Apache2

Tags: apache, wowza, http-live-streaming, proxypass, m3u8

I have a server Devian Wheezy with apache2 and WowzaStremaingEngine (WSE).

- I'm using RTMP for desktop player versión (over port 80 with Apache ProxyPass) solution found here: 
  http://www.keendevelopment.ch/running-apache-and-wowzaflash-media-serverred5-on-port-80-at-the-same-time/ and work fine for me :-)
- HLS for android and iOS (with wowza over 1935 at the moment)
- And Apache (over standard port 80) for the web page with JWPlayer to reproduce the streaming.

I want to use port 80 for all the services! There is a way to resolve it without buying another IP adress?

I try the same way I use with RTMP, but it seems not work.. with 404 error when try to load m3u8 file, maybe I'm making something wrong. I include simply the next line in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default`

```
ProxyPass "^/(.*\.m3u8)$" http://localhost:1935/$1
```

Actually I use a URL with the next format to play the stream using Wowza (don't have the m3u8 files, using smil format to determine the qualities)

`http://my.domain.com:1935/myVodApp/smil:multibitrate.smil/playlist.m3u8`

SMIL example file for WOWZA (Generated when video transcoding process finished)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<smil title="multibitrate.mp4">
  <body>
    <switch>
      <video height="360" src="multibitrate_360.mp4" systemLanguage="spa" width="640">
          <param name="videoBitrate" value="500000" valuetype="data"></param>
          <param name="audioBitrate" value="64000" valuetype="data"></param>
        </video>
        <video height="480" src="multibitrate_480.mp4" systemLanguage="spa" width="854">
          <param name="videoBitrate" value="1200000" valuetype="data"></param>
          <param name="audioBitrate" value="96000" valuetype="data"></param>
        </video>
        <video height="720" src="multibitrate_720.mp4" systemLanguage="spa" width="1280">
          <param name="videoBitrate" value="3000000" valuetype="data"></param>
          <param name="audioBitrate" value="128000" valuetype="data"></param>
        </video>
        <video height="1080" src="multibitrate_1080.mp4" systemLanguage="spa" width="1920">
          <param name="videoBitrate" value="8000000" valuetype="data"></param>
          <param name="audioBitrate" value="192000" valuetype="data"></param>
        </video>
      </switch>
    </body>
  </smil>
```

My first question, thanks in advance

Comment: Add Mime Type  in `httpd.conf`

`AddType application/x-mpegURL .m3u8`
`AddType video/MP2T .ts`

Comment: @MarmiK I think Is not the same problem, I want serve the HLS with WowzaStremaingEngine (WSE), no with apache. I Want to use ProxyPass only how a proxy, and serve HLS flux with WSE

Comment: Okay, try adding mime type, that should help, apache by default does not support this mime type, we need to add it manually. if it is already there, than we will look some other cause.

Comment: I add both lines in my apache2.conf file and restart apache2, and same response, 404 (not found).
But using port 1935 in the same URL works correctly!

Comment: add that in `httpd.conf` not in apache2.conf

Comment: if you are using linux based server `/etc/apache2/mods-available/mime.conf` you can change it here also.

Comment: I use Devian Wheezy. My apache2 no have `httpd.conf`, I use `apache2.conf` instead. 
I try adding mime-types in config file, in htcaccess and in mime.conf, and still the same result, `playlist.m3u8 404 (Not Found)`, :-/
Any new idea?

Comment: Check this https://www.wowza.com/community/questions/1269/m3u8-file-location.html